# Parenthesis Checking Using Stack Python

Tags: python-3.x, stack

I am learning data structures in Python and working on stacks. I am trying to create a code that uses stacks to match the parenthesis in an expression, however I am not getting the right answer. This needs to be done without the use of Python libraries.

```
class Stack():
    def __init__(self):  # Initialize a new stack
        self._items = []
        self._size = 0
        self._top = -1

    def push(self, new_item):  #  Append the new item to the stack 
        self._items.append(new_item)
        self._top += 1
        self._size += 1
        self._items[self._top] = new_item

    def pop(self):  # Remove and return the last item from the stack
        old_item = self._items[self._top]
        self._top -= 1
        self._size -= 1
        return old_item

    def size(self):  # Return the total number of elements in the stack
       return len(self._items)

    def isEmpty(self):  #  Return True if the stack is empty and False if it is not empty 
        if self._items == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def peek(self):   # Return the element at the top of the stack or return None if the stack is
```

empty
if self.isEmpty():
return None
else:
return self._items[self._top]

```
def check_Par(exp):
    opening = ['(', '[', '{']
    closing = [')', ']', '}']
    balanced = True
    s = Stack()

    for x in exp:
        if x in opening:
            s.push(x)
        elif x in closing:
            position = s.pop()
            if closing.index(x) and opening.index(position):
                balanced = True
            else:
                balanced = False
            pass      

    if s.isEmpty():
        balanced = False
    return balanced    

exp1 = "(2)+(-5)" # True
exp2 = "((2))*((3))" # True
exp3 = "(4))]" #False

print(check_Par(exp1))
print(check_Par(exp2))
print(check_Par(exp3))
```

I get an error for line 14 IndexError: list index out of range

Also, I know the for loop is not completed and I am having a hard time fix it.
Any advice it would be greatly appreciated.
Lois

Comment: This doesn't answer your problem, but can use a `list` directly instead of making your own `stack` class. You can use `list.append` and `list.pop`.

Comment: Do you really need to implement stack?

Comment: @Moosefeather - I know that list.append will get me the right answer, however, i need to use the stack class....

Comment: @ toRex - unfortunately yes.

Comment: @Lois You are getting IndexError because `s.pop()` gets called when `s._top < 0 and s._size  == 0` at some point.

Comment: @Moosefeather - any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: @Lois actually the `isEmpty` method is completely wrong, it will always return `False`.

Comment: @Moosefeather - are you referring to isEmpty in the stack class or in the check_par function?

Comment: Both, they're the same, in `check_Par` you're just calling the method from the Stack object. Hope my answer helps.

Comment: @Moosefeather thank you

Comment: @Moosefeather  - Do you mind elaborating a bit more on your answer? If the purpose is to use the Stack class to check if the parenthesis are balanced shouldn't the isEmpty() from the Stack class be used, the same way the pop() is? or do I have this all wrong???

Comment: @Lois `isEmpty` should tell you whether your stack object is empty or not. With lists it's the equivalent of doing `len(lst) > 0` or `not lst`. So you can replace the `not stack` with `stack.isEmpty()` (Assuming `isEmpty` works correctly). Finally, `lst.pop()` removes the element at the top of the stack and returns it. You can always check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) or search for these questions yourself).

Comment: Sorry I mean't `len(lst) == 0` not `len(lst) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a `list` as a stack, you can translate it to your stack class:

```
closing_to_opening = {')': '(', ']': '[', '}': '{'}
opening = list(closing_to_opening.values())

def check_par(exp):
    stack = []
    for c in exp:
        if c in opening:
            stack.append(c)
        elif c in closing_to_opening:
            if not stack or stack.pop() != closing_to_opening[c]:
                # The above checks '(' <-> ')', '[' <-> ']' etc
                return False
    # return True if stack is empty:
    return not stack
```